# problems with implenting OpenID with Google Apps Domain

Tags: openid

I am using lightopenID and am still using the example-google.php file included.

I have edited the $openid->identity to

```
$openid->identity = 'https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/site-xrds?hd=[my-google-app-domain]';
```

and everything works fine. When i click the Login With Google button, i get directed to the Google apps domain. I sign in and it ok...but when it redirects back to my localhost where i am testing the script, i get the following error message:

No OpenID Server found at [my-google-app-domain]

Can anybody explain what is going on here?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add a few files to your server, and a few lines to your .htaccess file, like this:

http://jeremiahlee.com/blog/2009/09/28/how-to-setup-openid-with-google-apps/

Not necessary for regular Google Accounts, only when you want to force them into Google Apps  on a specific domain.

As for "what is going on here?": I have no idea ?:/